# Denoising an Image Using Kalman Filter

Tags: c++, filtering, kalman-filter

I am trying to denoise a image using a kalman filter.
I am not taking any control parameters[B], hence it is a zero matrix. 
So my question is , **What should be the process noise [Qt] and measurement noise[Rt].**
Since I am taking my control parameter as zero. Should my process noise [Qt] also be zero.

And on what basis i should choose the magnitude of measurement noise [Rt].

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you are choosing a Kalman filter for image denoising?

Comment: i am estimating the next pixel based on the neighbouring pixel and i am taking the noised image pixel value as the measurement. For the estimating part KF is being used.

Answer (score 1):

My take on the subject would be:

1. The Measurement Noise should be calibrated according to the additive noise level of the image (Due to the camera's sensor).
2. The Process Noise should be calibrated according to the Gradients of the image.

The most important thing would be how to set the order you make the photo from 2D into 1D.
Just using the [Vectorization Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29) won't cut it.
Moreover, I'm pretty sure it should be done in 2 passes, Kalman Filter and Kalman Smoother.

Yet, I think the path from one pixel to another is the most important choice for a good result.
I'd bet on the most smooth path.
Let's see if other people come with ideas...